# Trying to train a convolutional neural network using an image dataset saved as a numpy array in pickle

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, numpy-ndarray

Trying to train a convolutional neural network using tensorflow and keras on python 3 in an anaconda environment. I think it's to do with how the dataset was saved in pickle previously but not completely sure

This is the error I keep getting:

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'int'>"})
```

This is my code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

import pickle

pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)

pickle_in = open("Y.pickle","rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)

X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=3, validation_split=0.3)
```

Comment: Hello user6282730!  It's not quite clear what exactly you are trying to ask.  Could you please rephrase this post into the form of a question?

Answer (score 0):

This code and question has been asked on StackExchange before:

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/60035/keras-error-failed-to-find-data-adapter-that-can-handle-input-while-trying-to

edit:
To fix your problem, you can try to change how you import the data and make sure it's a valid numpy array.
At the top, **import numpy as np** and then change where you load the data and define X and y to: **X = np.asarray(pickle.load(open("X.pickle", "rb")))** and then: **y = np.asarray(pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb")))**

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue however it works after importing NumPy.

```
import numpy as np 

pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X = np.asarray(pickle.load(pickle_in))

pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb")
y = np.asarray(pickle.load(pickle_in))
```